# Insert abstract nested class in simple?

Tags: java

Is't possible? Obvious that B has some abstract methods.

```
class A{

   //nested abstract class with some abstract methods
   class B extends AbstractClass{

   }

}
```

Comment: And it's a matter of running and trying to see what happens :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437922/why-nested-abstract-class-in-java for more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course it can be done:

```
public class Test
{
    abstract class AbstractClass
    {

    }

    class B extends AbstractClass
    {

    }
}
```

But why didn't you do it?