# is it possible to implement a typescript abstract inner class?

Tags: java, typescript, functional-programming, abstract-class, inner-classes

How do I write an abstract inner class like this in typescript?

```
// java code
public abstract class StringMap {

 abstract static class Builder<T extends Builder<?, ?>, I> {
   protected final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    protected Builder(Map<String, String> map) {
      this.map.putAll(emptyMapIfNull(map));
    }

   abstract T self();

    public abstract I build();

    public T put(String key, String value) {
      this.map.put(key, value);
      return self();
    }
 }

}
```

This is what I have so far but it will not build for multiple reasons. Can someone point me in the direction of how to convert the java version into typescript?

```
// typescript code
export abstract class StringMap {
 // it will not allow me to make this Builder assignment abstract 
 // which causes errors for the self and build function within it

 public static Builder =  class Builder<T extends Builder<any, any>, I> {
    constructor(map: Map<string, string>) {
     // implement putAll here
    }

    protected readonly map: Map<string, string> = new Map();

    abstract build(): I;

    public put(key: string, value: string): T {
      this.map.set(key, value);

      return this;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This has been helpful. Maybe I can use an interface instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437922/why-nested-abstract-class-in-java

Comment: There is no support in TS for abstract static things, as mentioned in [ms/TS#34516](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34516).  Not sure why you need this, but you could work around it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBR9xN).  Note that I dispensed with your explicit F-bounded polymorphism because TS has [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types); unless you're asking about F-bounded quantification, maybe you could remove that from your example? Otherwise there's too much going on in the question.

Comment: Thank you for taking a stab at this. I am trying to implement an SDK for a project using functional programming. It has proved to have low defects using this design but I know typescript may not have all of the same capabilities.

Comment: I like your typescript playground I will see if this can work. tyvm!!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.  In the mean time, please consider [edit]ing the question code to be a [mre] that doesn't include too many things you're not asking about.  To be clear, TS doesn't need Java's `self()` and `class Foo<T extends Foo<T>>` recursive generics if the goal is just to refer to the implementing subclass with `T`; there is a type named `this` which works that way out of the box.  So you can minimize your example to [this code here](https://tsplay.dev/mpLY7m).

Comment: OK and yes I agree that ts doesnt need self but I do believe I need class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> recursive generics because this StringMap will be used extensively for other locator classes. So I probably got ahead of myself. I am using your first example now and it is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither JavaScript nor TypeScript have true "inner" or "nested" classes (see [Nested ES6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784375/nested-es6-classes)) where you just  [declare a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) inside another class.

```
// THIS IS NOT VALID, DON'T DO THIS
class Foo { 
    class Bar { } // nope
    static class Baz { } // nope
}
```

Instead you could give the outer class an instance or static *member* whose type is a class constructor.  It's easy enough to initialize these with [class expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class), to much the same effect:

```
class Foo {
    Bar = class Bar { } // okay
    static Baz = class Baz { } // okay
}
```

Unfortunately, you want your inner class to be *abstract*, and TypeScript does not support abstract class expressions; see [microsoft/TypeScript#4578](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4578) for the declined feature request:

```
// THIS IS NOT VALID, DON'T DO THIS
class Foo {
    Bar = abstract class Bar { } // nope
    static Baz = abstract class Baz { } // nope
}
```

To work around *that*, one might write abstract class declarations in an appropriate scope and then assign them to relevant properties.  This is helped by [class property inference from initialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#class-property-inference-from-constructors) and [`static` initialization blocks in classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#static-blocks-in-classes):

```
class Foo {
    Bar; // type inferred from constructor initialization
    constructor() {
        abstract class Bar { } // declaration
        this.Bar = Bar; // initialization
    }

    static Baz; // type inferred from static initialization
    static {
        abstract class Baz { } // declaration
        this.Baz = Baz; // initialization
    }
}
```

In the above, `Bar` is an abstract instance-nested class, and `Baz` is an abstract static-nested class:

```
const foo = new Foo();
new foo.Bar(); // error, abstract
class MyBar extends foo.Bar { }
new MyBar(); // okay

new Foo.Baz(); // error, abstract
class MyBaz extends Foo.Baz { }
new MyBaz(); // okay
```

---

So, in your example, you could do something like

```
abstract class StringMap {
    public static Builder;
    static {
        abstract class Builder<I> {
            constructor(map: Map<string, string>) { }
            protected readonly map: Map<string, string> = new Map();
            abstract build(): I;
            public put(key: string, value: string): this {
                this.map.set(key, value);
                return this;
            }
        }
        this.Builder = Builder;
    }
}
```

That compiles fine as long as you aren't trying to generate declaration files via [the `--declaration` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#declaration), since it would require the compiler to provide declarations for undeclared types with `protected` things and... well, it's kind of a mess; see [microsoft/TypeScript#35822](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35822).  Workarounds include removing `protected` modifiers, or moving scopes around so the class with `protected` members has an exportable name.  That's easy-ish for static-nested classes:

```
abstract class Builder<I> {
    constructor(map: Map<string, string>) { }
    protected readonly map: Map<string, string> = new Map();
    abstract build(): I;
    public put(key: string, value: string): this {
        this.map.set(key, value);
        return this;
    }
}

abstract class StringMap {
    public static Builder = Builder;
}
```

But the particular solution for how to deal with declaration files will depend on your use cases, so I'll stop there.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAdg9gDgpgKAMYBsCGBnDYBiUpgDeYCYZYqm2AQmgE5FgC+p5GALmuwJZIXpYwtAF6MmJFiGAJkA7HgKFWZWgwC8-KkPpjlYDl17bRGyoJG6WCUJFhwS5TYIVE9j1WA1oARhzpokdicaHWIWR0cDHj4LL192f0Dg411HSWkINABbOAwYAPsAeQBrNABPV0czeXxKiJV6AG43ciQoCD8AV0CoOgAKAEo6+scfPwCg6u0GMJb69gALbgwAOg8NVWaR5jn9TmjjLZGooyVt0fjEybkU2fPyReW1tBND3fDyKyr2jjAAM1qGggcAA7rh8IMjmRgWCAVBnv0Bo0wMBgGA4HQ6L0ADRgMYJCZ6KYAWTKHjgAA92HAIAATbBwhGpcgwsCk1SQlFoqClMoyRyshTPYSc1HozE4vGXQlVG7sl7oqk0+ng+EWO4s0FsskvUXc3kyKz4q7JADKCW4EAA5sS0DBhmAYJ1vCgjCcYp1uChaRioXtDHwziNjRNktRPd6MQAeACSAD4Hds2h0Et12L0+lk7QAuNl2qN+S1W3GF61xoYa+6gGBY6mBOC0qRgOhwNC09ooCpZmC520wAsW60lwdWhNArV9yG7C7jJLeCO0wa5mN+7ZOl1GJ3sPrFOBlXOl4tgABuaBQnTgB5HA1zj2wQfujjvK27KwwcG3u7KuNP57gSOnEYW3YTo6AgMA71XEYPnqGCImfcMvR9dQhAXX09BYKwEBDJIpkQyM6FjBMHwoH5Ux6fpu17fND2HOgi3LZkyBrKA62pWlm1bdsIE7MAqLzftaL2eiy08SAJztKcZwJOcFyXMAVz0ddXT4Lcdz3K8RKPX8L00osbwgpZ712Z9X3fT89x-M8LwA7ZgNA8DIIwhAWBw64tHNLS+wAJgdZS3X2Ix8OQsTgvQqwgA)

Comment: Fantastic man! This is really helping me learn. I really appreciate it!!!